# How to enable a disabled text box onclick a button using angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a text box which is disabled using simple disabled html tag.I need to enable it when I click enable button, again I need to disable it when click disable button.
Here is the code below -

### app.component.html

```
<input  type="text" disabled value="Sample text box">

<button (click)="enable()" type="button">Enable</button>
<button (click)="disable()" type="button">Disable</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
enable(){

}

disable(){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<input  type="text" [disabled]='toggleButton' value="Sample text box">

<button (click)="enable()" type="button">Enable</button>
<button (click)="disable()" type="button">Disable</button>
```

TS

```
export class pageName {
     public toggleButton: boolean = false;

     constructor(){}


    enable(){
       this.toggleButton = false
    }

    disable(){
       this.toggleButton = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need TypeScript for this, you can reference the input from within the template

```html
<input #input type="text" disabled value="Sample text box">

<button (click)="input.disabled = false" type="button">Enable</button>
<button (click)="input.disabled = true" type="button">Disable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" [disabled]="isDisabled" value="Sample text box">
```

TS:

`isDisabled:boolean = false;`

```
enable(){
   this.isDisabled = false
}

disable(){
   this.isDisabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach:

```html
<input  type="text" [disabled]="isDisabled" value="Sample text box">

<button (click)="isDisabled = false" type="button">Enable</button>
<button (click)="isDisabled = true" type="button">Disable</button>
```

Also, `disabled` is **not a tag**, is an [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)